# How to create file in a Windows mounted partition?

Tags: mount, ntfs

I can mount the Windows partition in my Ubuntu installation but I don't seem to be able to create or paste files in to the mounted partition. I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: was your windows system shut down correctly? or are you talking about sharing files across a network?

Comment: You're not mounting it correctly. More information - http://askubuntu.com/questions/5069/cant-set-permissions-for-files-on-an-ntfs-partition/ (the information is for automount, however you can specify the options while mounting through the terminal too)

Answer (score 2):

If you mounted from Nautilus, it uses a special GNOME API (gio/gvfs). You can't access the files from command line or non-gnome-aware programs. But there is a bridge:

You should install [gvfs-fuse](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gvfs-fuse)

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs-fuse
```

and restart Nautilus (perhaps `killall -HUP nautilus` is enough)

Comment: It didnt works. It says read only file system.

Comment: when? how? could you be more specific?

Comment: Actually i installed the gvfs-fuse. Then i killed all the Nautilus. But the problem didnt go.

Comment: Actually i tried with LIVE CD and make some fsck command. It works. Thanks for your reponses.