# How to create a wifi network to share files between a Ubuntu 12.04 PC and windows 7 (32 bit) PC

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create file in windows share?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15573/how-to-create-file-in-windows-share)

I want to share files with a Windows 7 (32 Bit) Laptop. I have another laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 installed. How can I share files using a WiFi network over the two systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll have to connect them. If they are connected to the same router, you can skip this step, else create ad Ad-Hoc network and connect them together. You'll have to set the IP for both computers.

After that, you'll have to enable file-sharing. Look at [samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/samba-fileserver.html) to enable share from ubuntu to windows. To share from windows to ubuntu, you'll just have to share the folder with the standard file-sharing settings of windows. Then just type in nautilus (file explorer, to type press CTRL+L) smb://HostIP/ (Replace HostIP according to the IP of the remote computer).