# Are my permissions correct for sharing files with Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, permissions, fstab

I have Kubuntu 12.04.01 installed on partition */dev/sdb2* of my dual boot Computer. */sda1* carries Windows XP, XP Program files and some data files. */sda2* and */sdb1* carry more data, music and pictures, mostly going back to the bad old Windows-only days.

I cannot (and don't want to) access */sdb2* from XP but can access all files from Kubuntu and do most things I want. Occasionally, working in Linux, I can't do what I think I should be possible on files or directories in */sda2* and */sdb1*. The restrictions happen whether I created the file in XP or Linux, though they don't apply if I use a directory in */sdb2*. I suspect that my permissions are not as they should be.

One such restriction is that, in Dolphin, if I right-click a file and enter Properties>Permissions, any change is successful only for files in */sdb2*

My **etc/fstab** file (expanded for me by someone with much greater experience of Linux) is as follows:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=bcc24647-8a34-46d2-afe6-b0f747c18631 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
UUID=ef2d585d-bd09-46e0-ad5e-cf63c6cda913 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sda1       /media/System ntfs-3g defaults,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0077 0 0
/dev/sda2       /media/Samples ntfs-3g defaults,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0077 0 0
/dev/sdb1       /media/Audio ntfs-3g defaults,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0077 0 0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

Is there something which should be altered here, or is there another file elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I understand that you are facing problem with File Permissions.

As you have said, `/sda2` and `/sdb1` are both `ntfs` file systems.

NTFS file systems don't support the concept of file permissions.

Refer [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5069/cant-set-permissions-for-files-on-an-ntfs-partition) for more details.

This is the reason you are facing problems with file permissions in `/sda2` and `/sdb1` partitions.

Comment: Thanks Karthik, I believe that NTFS partitions have a different concept of file permissions in that a folder or file can be made "sharing" though the default is otherwise. It is possible that I might work around the problem by making all my NTFS folders sharing in Windows, though this would create different problems. I will look more at the post you have quoted to see what might be done in fstab by dmask, umask etc, though I can't quite get my head round them yet.

Comment: I accept that Karthik's answer gives the reason why I can't alter NTFS permissions in Dolphin, but it does not fully explain  why I can freely open and alter a spreadsheet, for example, on an NTFS partition in either Windows or Linux, but sometimes not save a new project created in Linux to a file on the same partition.