# Deluge getting permission denied when trying to download to a mounted drive

Tags: 12.10, permissions, deluge

Getting permission denied when trying to download or move_storage of a torrent to a mounted drive (saw the error with deluded).

The drive is an internal HDD mounted with this command at `/etc/fstab`.

```
/media/username/584C1E8B4C1E63D2    ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.utf8  0   0
```

What's the solution to this?

*OS: Ubuntu 12.10, 64bit*

Comment: Can you create any files on that drive as your "normal" user?

Comment: @Sergey: Nope..Should I change the ownership of this driver? With chown maybe? But why I don't have rights to create files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NTFS is not a "proper" Linux file system - it does not support traditional Unix permissions. Because of that, you need to specify an option when mounting the partition which tells the ntfs driver which permissions to report for all files and directories. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5069/cant-set-permissions-for-files-on-an-ntfs-partition) for more details.