# Setting up Deluge Web

Tags: permissions, deluge

I have a second hard drive which is mounted on startup. The file system of the second hard drive is also ext4. The mount point is `/home/username/mydata`:

```
UUID=30916bc6-913e-44e4-979c-e158f11d9abf /home/username/mydata    ext4 nodev,nosuid,noexec  0    1
```

I also have a deluge and deluge-web installation.

I changed the download directories. All new directories for downloads are inside `/home/username/mydata/deluge`. I also run these commands:

```
sudo chown -R deluge:deluge /home/username/mydata/deluge
sudo chmod -R 775 deluge /home/username/mydata/deluge
```

However, when I add a torrent I get this error:

```
Status: Permission denied: /home/username/mydata/deluge/temp/{TorrentFileName}
```

I don't know what I am missing or why is not working.

**UPDATE**

The output of namei -lx /home/agusgambina/mydata/deluge/temp/

```
f: /home/agusgambina/mydata/deluge/temp/
Drwxr-xr-x root        root        /
drwxr-xr-x root        root        home
drwxr-xr-x agusgambina agusgambina agusgambina
Drwx------ agusgambina agusgambina mydata
drwxrwxr-x deluge      deluge      deluge
drwxrwxr-x deluge      deluge      temp
```

Comment: If the second drive is NTFS then likely the mount permissions are not correct, see http://askubuntu.com/a/235116/8570

Comment: @Cas thank you for your comment. The partition is not NTFS is ext4.

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `namei -lx /home/username/mydata/deluge/temp/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mydata` directory has permissions only for your user:

```
Drwx------ agusgambina agusgambina mydata
```

The deluge user cannot access anything within `mydata` without execute permission on it (see [Accessing files in a directory without x-permission?](https://askubuntu.com/q/83788/158442)). So, grant execute permissions on the directory:

```
chmod o+x /home/agusgambina/mydata
```

Other permissions seem fine.